# Prove that $\frac{(1-x)^{y(1-x)}}{(1- xy)^{1-xy}} < 1$, when $0 < x < 1$, $y > 1$ and $xy < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

If $0 < x <  1$, $y > 1$ and $xy < 1$,
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{nx,nx,\cdots,n(1 - yx)}}{\binom{n}{nx,n(1-x)}} \sim \left(\frac{(1-x)^{y(1-x)}}{(1- xy)^{1-xy}}\right)^{\!n} = o(1)
$$
only if
$$
\frac{(1-x)^{y(1-x)}}{(1- xy)^{1-xy}} < 1.
$$ But I cannot find the appropriate way to prove this. Hence I am asking all for your kind help to solve this problem.

Comment: fix $y>1$ and take $f(x)=(1-xy)\log (1-xy)-y(1-x)\log(1-x)$ defined on $[0,1/y]$; simple computation shows that $f' >0 , x >0$ so $f$ increases strictly and $f(0)=0$ hence $f(x) >0$ etc

Comment: Thanks @Conrad for the proof. I elaborated it further as, $f' = -y (\log (1-xy) +1)  + y(\log(1-x) + 1) =  y \log\frac{1-x}{1-xy}  > 0$.

Comment: @Conrad kindly add your answer in answer mode. I have to cite this in a paper.